# How to Display a Message after every 5 seconds in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of messages and I want to display each message in that array inside the Header component of my React page.

const array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

I want to display each one of those messages inside a

tag, also I need a clear timeout function so that the time doesn't speed up after every click and it should go to the next message after 5 seconds, can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple loop over the array, that is how you would do it:

```js
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

counter = 0;
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  console.log(array[counter % array.length]); //e.g. "a", "b"
  //you can do everything with the return value (put it in an a tag)
  counter++;
}, 5000);
```

to clear the interval, you can do this:

```js
clearInterval(interval);
```

I'm not sure what you want to do with the click event. Please provide further information for that.